# Prefix all lines on standard error

Tags: bash

Is this the best way to prefix all lines written by a Bash script to standard error?

```
#! /bin/bash

exec 3>&2
exec 2> >(sed 's/^/ERROR: /' >&3)

echo stdout
echo stderr >&2
```

I am wondering, if I have to close file descriptor 3.

Answer (score 7):

There's not a lot to review here.  It's Valgrind clean, though that's not difficult to achieve.

Certainly consider closing stream 3, unless you want to keep a means to emit unprefixed stderr messages.

One shortcoming is that the shell won't wait for `sed` to finish when it terminates.  If the last process's output is still being filtered at this point, then you may fail to capture it - I observed this (repeatably) when running the program in Emacs `compilation-mode`.

One way you can improve on this if you're using GNU sed is by passing `-u` ("unbuffered") flag to sed.  If you don't have GNU sed but do have GNU coreutils, then the `stdbuf` utility could make sed line-buffered for you:

```
stdbuf -oL -iL sed 's/^/ERROR: /'
```

With any sed, we could (and should) close stderr when we terminate and wait for sed to finish to be sure of catching all error output.

---

## Modified code

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3>&2
exec 2> >(sed -u 's/^/ERROR: /' >&3)
exec 3>&-
# shellcheck disable=SC2064
trap "exec 2>&-; wait $!" EXIT

echo stdout
echo stderr >&2
```

Comment: It is possible to wait for the process substitution. The pid of the child process is in `$!` after the `exec`. In order to flush the output of the child process, it is sufficient to close the input fd, which is fd 2 of the parent. After that one can wait for the child pid.

Comment: Good suggestion; thanks @ceving.  I've made the appropriate change.

Comment: That was a typo - `&1` where I meant `&-`.  Sorry!